# Send Email without SMTP protocol

Tags: c#, email, smtp, client, send

VB can be used to send emails that can be viewed in any email client as shown below (no client specified)

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "Example CDO Message" 
objMessage.From = "me@my.com" 
objMessage.To = "test@paulsadowski.com" 
objMessage.TextBody = "This is some sample message text." 
objMessage.Send
```

Can c# send emails without specifying the smtp client?

Comment: If you want to use CDO: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310221

Answer (score 0):

VB uses a local SMTP Server on your machine.
See [here](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm) for details.

To do the same in C# have a look at this question: [convert vb email send code to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331372/convert-vb-email-send-code-to-c-sharp)

Comment: I get the error SMTP Host was not specified when trying the link: convert vb email send code to c#